# for-loop over directory to zip subdirectories

Tags: bash, for-loop

My question is really simple but it's been too long since I last read bash-scripts so I cannot understand bash anymore...

I have a folder (name containing spaces) which has x subfolders. Now I want to zip each subfolder in its own zip archive.

The following script is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
for folder in $1/* do
zip -r "${folder%/}" "${folder%/}"
done
```

every time I try to execute it with `./test.sh .` I just get

```
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `zip'
./test.sh: line 4: `zip -r "${folder%/}" "${folder%/}"'
```

what is wrong with my thoughts and why?

if I enter a variable (e.g. `file="subfolder i want to zip"`) in the shell and execute `zip -r "${file}" "${file}"` it just works fine for the one folder.

I appreciate any help and hope my question can be solved easily (so I'm able to understand it).
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Watch out for the `cd $1`, if that fails or if the script is not passed a parameter it could perform operations in the wrong directories.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the tip, I actually ran it without any parameters before I asked here and it tried to zip some of my home folder contents. Luckily it's fixed very quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use shell tools, you can use a for loop as illustrated in other answers. If you can afford calling another application like `find`, here's a one-liner:

```
find "${1}" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec zip -r "{}.zip" "{}" \;
```

Comment: ok, I just tested it and I've to say, that's awesome, I can even pass my new "script" (a 2-liner in my bin directory xD) directories containing spaces! thanks a lot.

Comment: I just realized that you can add a `%/` to get rid of the second slash: `find "${1%/}" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec zip -r "{}.zip" "{}" \;`

Answer (score 6):

Try this -

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
for folder in $1/*
do
zip -r "${folder%/}" "${folder%/}"
done
```

Either put `";"` after `$1/*` or use do in next line.

Comment: oh my god... just a semicolon which robs me 2 hours of my time -.-
thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need a semicolon before the `do`:

```
for folder in $1/*; do
  zip -r "${folder%/}" "${folder%/}"
done
```

This is needed to disambiguate the grammar, specifically to indicate "no more strings to iterate over". Eg. this allows to iterate over shell keywords:

```
for k in do if done; do
  ...
done
```

Comment: oh my god... just a semicolon which robs me 2 hours of my time -.-
I cannot think of an example why I would want to loop over bash keywords but its really impressive. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already mentioned it, but you do need a semi color before the `do`

I would also recommend checking if you are really zipping up a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
for folder in $1/* ; do
    [ -d $folder ] && zip -r "${folder%/}" "${folder%/}"
done
```

Comment: ah ok, I implemented the folder-check, thanks a lot.